# SUM MySQL column when having JOINs

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a newbie issue trying to do a SUM of results set from MySQL.

Having 2 tables:

```
formalities
  - id
  - total
  - group_id
  - book_id
  - status_id

payments
  - id
  - amount
  - formality_id (FK)
```

Considering 1:N relations on formalities, where 1 `formality` could have 1 or more `payments`.
I need to get the total SUM in 2 ways:

The first one, by getting the total from `formalities.total`, which is working as expected:

```
SELECT SUM(formalities.total)
FROM formalities
WHERE group_id = 2 AND book_id = 23 AND status_id IN (1,3)
```

The second one, by getting the total from `payments.amount`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(f.amount) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        payments.amount
    FROM payments
    JOIN formalities ON payments.formality_id = formalities.id AND formalities.group_id = 2 AND formalities.book_id = 23 AND formalities.status_id IN (1,3)
    GROUP BY payments.id
) f
```

FYI:

- All payments are related to a formality.
- All formalities have at least 1 payment.
- The `formalities.total` is always equal to the SUM of its `payments.amount`

I'm wondering what's wrong with my 2nd query since totals don't match.

BTW, I'm working on a recently migrated DB so this may be related to a wrong migration, but I need to be sure that my queries are doing what I'm looking for.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the query in the derived table `f` is invalid. `payments.amount` either has to be in the `GROUP BY` clause or passed to an aggregation function. Older MySQL or badly configured versions of MySQL do allow that rule to broken without further warning. But it might produce funny and maybe not even reproducible results.

```
SELECT sum(p.amount)
       FROM formalities f
            LEFT JOIN payments p
                      ON p.formality_id = f.id
       WHERE f.group_id = 2
             AND f.book_id = 23
             AND f.status_id IN (1, 3);
```

should give you the result you want as far as I understand your question.

One other thing: It seems like `formalities.total` is meant to hold the the sum of all `payments.amount` for that formality. If that is true, drop the column `formalities.total`. It is redundant and might lead to inconsistencies -- probably what you're experiencing right now. The total amount should not be materialized. For convenience you can create a view that includes the total though. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIEW formalities_with_total
AS
SELECT f.id,
       sum(p.amount) total,
       f.group_id,
       f.book_id,
       f.status_id
       FROM formalities f
            LEFT JOIN payments p
                      ON p.formality_id = f.id
       GROUP BY f.id,
                f.group_id,
                f.book_id,
                f.status_id;
```

Comment: I understand your point and I appreciate your explanation about the invalid query. I will move forward as per your recommendation from now. Fortunately, I found that both, my query and yours, return the same result so this is in fact a migration issue.
In regards to the materialized total, It was done because my inexperience and need to fetch a list of formalities from a HUGE table (more than 3 million records). That's why I did that, to avoid left joins and for performance issues.

Comment: To my mind, VIEWs in MySQL serve no useful purpose, because queries against them cannot utilise underlying indexes

Comment: @Strawberry so VIEWS don't use table indexes which means a poor query performance? I see in MySQL docs this: "view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables". Not sure what it means.

Comment: Yep; that's what I said

Comment: @Strawberry: Hmm, doesn't seem to bad to me in 8.0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37c7f70504488c228727ba51f0698f38 And not totally bad down till 5.5.

Comment: Well maybe I'm a bit out of touch!

Comment: Although I can't help wondering if this is something to do with the way dbfiddle implements views, because the manual seems unequivocal on this point (although it wouldn't be the first time I'd misunderstood the manual)